# Linq to Entity casting

Tags: c#, linq, frameworks, entity

I have a problem with my Linq to Entity query.. Im trying to return a list  like so:

`List<InvoiceReportItem> cancelResults = (List<InvoiceReportItem>)(from cr in model.InvoiceReportItems
                                                                                  //join l in model.tblLicences on cr.LicenceAuto equals l.LicenceAuto
                                                                                  where cr.Report.Id == id
                                                                                  select cr);`

but its giving me the error:

> Unable to cast object of type >'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[LicExpiryNotModel_EF41.Model.InvoiceReportItem]' to > type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LicExpiryNotModel_EF41.Model.InvoiceReportItem]'.

Does anyone have any idea why its giving this error? driving me crazy! :(

Thanks in advance
Neil

Comment: don't cast just put `.ToList()` behind te query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)()

```
List<InvoiceReportItem> cancelResults = 
 (from cr in model.InvoiceReportItems 
  join l in model.tblLicences on cr.LicenceAuto equals l.LicenceAuto where cr.Report.Id == id 
  select cr).ToList();
```

Comment: i tried that, and it gives a compile error:  


'Error 3 Cannot convert method group 'ToList' to non-delegate type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<LicExpiryNotModel_EF41.Model.InvoiceReportItem>'. Did you intend to invoke the method? C:\sourceroot\LING\LING+Licensing\LING\LING_LicenceExpiryNotification\LicExpiryNotModel_EF41\LicenceExpiryNotification_WPF\MainWindow.xaml.cs 101 57 LicenceExpiryNotification_WPF'

Comment: Actually it did work! :) sorry i must have left out brackets last time or something!

Comment: @niallNoigeallach: If its working you can accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left to the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an `IQueryable` to a `List`, instead use the `.ToList()` method on the `IQueryable`, like this:

```
List<InvoiceReportItem> cancelResults = (from cr in model.InvoiceReportItems).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a query like this, LINQ defers execution and returns and IQueryable. This allows you to query further in the future if you want (e.g. adding extra where clauses). Th IQueryable generic can't be cast to a list.
As the others have suggested, call the ToList() on the code

```
List<InvoiceReportItem> cancelResults = (List<InvoiceReportItem>)(from cr in model.InvoiceReportItems //join l in model.tblLicences on cr.LicenceAuto equals l.LicenceAuto where cr.Report.Id == id select cr).ToList();
```